# Saving parent doesn't save child

Tags: ruby, orm, jruby, datamapper

I have:

```
module App
  module Data
    class TariffTestPrice
      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :tariff_id, Integer, :key => true
      property :test_id, Integer, :key => true
      property :price, Float # domyślnie nil

      belongs_to :tariff
      belongs_to :test
    end
  end
end



module App
  module Data
    class Tariff
      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :id, Serial
      property :name, String, :default => ''

      has n, :tariff_test_prices

      alias to_s name

      def used?
        !firms.empty?
      end

      def put(test, price)
        ttp = tariff_test_prices.first_or_new(:test => test)
        test.tariff_test_prices << ttp if ttp.dirty?
        ttp.price = price
      end

      def at(test)
        ttp = tariff_test_prices.first(:test => test)
        ttp ? ttp.price : nil
      end
    end
  end
end


module App
  module Data
    class Test
      include DataMapper::Resource

      property :id, Serial
      property :name, String, :default => ''

      has n, :tariff_test_prices

      belongs_to :test_type, :model => 'TestType', :child_key => [ :type_id ]
      alias type test_type

      alias to_s name

      def used?
        !visits.empty? || !tariffs.empty?
      end

      private

      def tariffs
        tariff_test_prices.map &:tariff
      end
    end
  end
end
```

When I put values test, price and save tariff it doesn't change anything in database:

```
        tariff.put(test, price)
        tariff.save # It doesn't save TariffTestPrice
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def put(test, price) do
  ttp = TariffTestPrice.first_or_create(:tariff => self, :test => test)
  ttp.price = price
  ttp.save
end
```

Comment: I know that. But I want to save TariffTestPrice by saving Tariff.

Comment: Unfortunately as far as my experience goes I've never seen datamapper achieve that - save the model instance, then update its attributes.